# uninitialized constant Car::PictureUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, controller, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to add a Picture Uploader in app/uploaders but am getting this error when loading my app:

```
uninitialized constant Car::PictureUploader on line 3 of car.rb
```

**app/models/car.rb**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :year, presence:true, length: { maximum: 4 }
  validates :brand, presence:true
```

**app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

I've gotten this error before when the file equivalent to picture_uploader.rb wasn't in the correct folder, but I think everything is in order here.  When I comment out line 3 in user.rb the page loads.  Any idea on how I can get my page to run?

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
::PictureUploader
```

Which specifies that it's just the class `PictureUploader` not a class `PictureUploader` within the namespace `Car`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error and had to manually kill the server process:

```
ps aux | grep server
kill [server process id]
```

For some reason shutting down the server with Ctrl+C earlier didn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your server. It'll fix the issue. Everything is ok in your code.